# Stop propagation of certain actions with certain payload in redux

Tags: javascript, redux

What is the recommended way to stop certain actions with certain payload from being dispatched to reducers?

I am currently using a `middleware` for that and just do not call the `next` function. But that seems wrong. Is there another concept in `redux` to handle this kind of scenario?
I've read about `Higher Order Stores` but have not really understood how they work :(

Comment: Why does that seem wrong?

Comment: because nothing in the docs mentions that kind of scenario. But only that you have to call `next`

Comment: I can think of three ways --- one is what you have suggested. Another one is to let the action dispatch and return state as is if payload matches your criteria. 

Another thing you can do is check payload where you are actually dispatching the action.

Comment: Analyse the payload before dispatching and if you dont want to send it dont dispatch the action.

Comment: Following this answer (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50353571/should-next-always-be-invoked-last-in-redux-middleware) its ok to not call `next()` in some cases.